# Binding image and text to listbox get exception index out of range

Tags: c#, exception, windows-8, listbox, windows-store-apps

I have listbox where I am binding image + text. When I add 15 items no problem but when I add more items 20 and more I get System.IndexOutOfRangeException. I find somewhere listbox can store only 32kb so I try use listview and I get the same System.IndexOutOfRangeException. Im using ObservableCollection can be overflow here or anyone have idea why I get System.IndexOutOfRangeException? I get this exception when items are adding to listbox.

```
    private ObservableCollection<BindingData> _rsMessages = new ObservableCollection<BindingData>();
    public ObservableCollection<BindingData> RSMessages
    {
        get { return _rsMessages; }
        set { _rsMessages = value; }
    }

public void initializeListboxRS()
    {
        foreach (var items in UniDB.returnListOfRSItems())
        {
            _rsMessages.Add(new BindingData
            {
                rssMessageText = items.tile,
                rssMessageDateTime = items.dateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm"),
                rssMessageImage = ByteArrayToBitmapImage(items.image),
                rssMessageLink = items.link
            });
            OnPropertyChanged("RSMessages");
        }
    }


 private BitmapImage ByteArrayToBitmapImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        ms.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());  //exception here
        ms.FlushAsync().AsTask().Wait();
        ms.Seek(0);
        bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

Comment: At which line from you code you are getting exception? Why are you using `async void` in method `initializeListboxRS()`? Where did you find that listbox can store only 32kb?

Comment: 1. async word is redundant I fogot delete it now is ok, 2. http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?451056-List-Box-max-item, 3. I get exception when I add new item to observable collection .

Comment: It's not 32 kb, 32K means 32,000. Listbox allows 32,000 items to display. K represents thousands. I think error is in `ByteArrayToBitmapImage(...)` method. Try to add object explicitly in the ObservableCollection, don't use `_rsMessages.Add(new BindingData{...});`. Then check each item in foreach which item is throwing the error. After that check what's wrong with that item.

Comment: yes you have true problem is in method BitmapImage ByteArrayToBitmapImage(byte[] byteArray). I get Exception:Thrown: "Index was outside the bounds of the array but I dont understand why. I add method code. I load bytes from sqlite DB so I think bytes are not demaged

Answer (score 0):

Your method implementation lacks `await` keyword. Try the below code.

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> ByteArrayToBitmapImage(byte[] byteArray)
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
    stream.Seek(0);

    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    return bitmapImage;
}

private ObservableCollection<BindingData> _rsMessages = new ObservableCollection<BindingData>();
public ObservableCollection<BindingData> RSMessages
{
    get { return _rsMessages; }
    set { _rsMessages = value; }
}

public async Task initializeListboxRS()
{
    foreach (var items in UniDB.returnListOfRSItems())
    {
        _rsMessages.Add(new BindingData
        {
            rssMessageText = items.tile,
            rssMessageDateTime = items.dateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm"),
            rssMessageImage = await ByteArrayToBitmapImage(items.image),
            rssMessageLink = items.link
        });
        OnPropertyChanged("RSMessages");
    }
}
```

Whenever you call method `initializeListboxRS()` use `await` prefix.

Comment: hm I try your solution but I still have the same exc: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dkwjkcbwouzgupc/lbOutofRange.png, only difference now is my previous code add text without image now dont show text if get exception on image. For example from 15 images show only 11 now and 4 images are not binded. I also try create new method which on lick on button add another 15 images from database and no I get exception Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: I recommend you to put debug break point in `ByteArrayToBitmapImage()` method and check for each foreach iteration whether `byteArray` argument is valid or not. I doubt `stream.Seek(0);` line is throwing error.

Comment: If it's non-confidential project can you please share the whole project via dropbox?

Comment: thx for your help, I have to figure this problem alone because you must be student in my country to access to databases and login to app. thank you for the efforts I think problem will be maybe in threads etc.